# Is there a better way to read many html url?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are series of commands I need to execute with bunch of `URLs` and `Sett.` values.

How can I make the code below cleaner?

```
import pandas as pd

url_ita_a = ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Serie-A')
df_ita_a = pd.read_html(url_ita_a)[0]
df2_ita_a = df_ita_a[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa', 'Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
zero_df_ita_a = df2_ita_a[(df2_ita_a['Punteggio'] == '0–0') & (df2_ita_a['Sett.'] > 15)]

url_tur_a = ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/26/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Super-Lig')
df_tur_a = pd.read_html(url_tur_a)[0]
df2_tur_a = df_tur_a[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa', 'Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
zero_df_tur_a = df2_tur_a[(df2_tur_a['Punteggio'] == '0–0') & (df2_tur_a['Sett.'] > 15)]

...
...
...

url_rom_a = ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/47/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Liga-I')
df_rom_a = pd.read_html(url_rom_a)[0]
df2_rom_a = df_rom_a[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa', 'Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
zero_df_rom_a = df2_rom_a[(df2_rom_a['Punteggio'] == '0–0') & (df2_rom_a['Sett.'] > 13)]

url_ind_a = ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/82/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Indian-Super-League')
df_ind_a = pd.read_html(url_ind_a)[0]
df2_ind_a = df_ind_a[['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa', 'Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
zero_df_ind_a = df2_ind_a[(df2_ind_a['Punteggio'] == '0–0') & (df2_ind_a['Sett.'] > 10)]

frames = [zero_df_ita_a, zero_df_tur_a, ... zero_df_rom_a,
          zero_df_ind_a]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Put the DF in a dictionary, and do this in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add all your `urls` and the `Sett.` values in list of tuples.
2. Iterate over them using `for` loop.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

urls = [('https://fbref.com/it/comp/11/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Serie-A', 15),
        ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/26/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Super-Lig', 15),
        ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/12/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-La-Liga', 13),
        ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/13/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Ligue-1', 13),
        ('https://fbref.com/it/comp/20/calendario/Risultati-e-partite-di-Bundesliga', 13)
        ] #Add all URLS and 'Sett.' values

frames = []

for url, sett in urls:
    df2 = pd.read_html(url)[0][['Sett.', 'Data', 'Casa', 'Punteggio', 'Ospiti']]
    frames.append(df2[(df2['Punteggio'] == '0–0') & (df2['Sett.'] > sett)]) #Here will come in handy the 'sett' variable

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

> I didn't manually add all the URLs into the list because there were so many of them.

Comment: Nice answer. Suggest replacing `for my_tuple in urls:` with `for url, sett in urls:`. One line shorter.

Comment: Wow didn't know that was a think thanks! :)

Comment: Please give the answer the `green arrow` so it will be accepted! :)